# Dojo Prevent onclick events from children nodes

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, event-delegation, dojox.mobile

I have programmatically created an ul like follows:

```
var paneaux= dojo.byId("personsListPane");

var list = new dojox.mobile.RoundRectList({
    id: 'personsList',
    select:"single",
}).placeAt(paneaux).startup();

var listaux=dojo.byId("personsList");

for (var i = 0, len = persons.length; i < len; i++){
    var person= persons[i];
    var li = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
        id:person.IdPerson,
        label: person.Surname + " " + person.Surname2 + ", " + person.Name,
        clickable : true,
    }, domConstruct.create("li", {}, listaux));

    li.startup();

    on(li, "click",  lang.hitch(this, function(evt){
        li= evt.target;
        var person = gpt._sessionData.userPersons.filter(function(obj){
            return obj.IdPerson==li.id;
        });                         
        gpt._sessionData.defaultPersonEmployee =person[0];
        initImpl();
    }));  
}
```

Which gives the following html result:

```
<li class="mblListItem mblListItemUnchecked" tabindex="0" id="1vxki6w6vb8uihiu9crhocy3e" widgetid="1vxki6w6vb8uihiu9crhocy3e" aria-selected="false" role="button">
    <div class="mblListItemRightIcon">
       <div title="" class="mblDomButtonArrow mblDomButton">
         <div> </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mblListItemLabel">López Ibarra, Alberto</div>
</li>
```

The problem is the following: When I click on the name of the person, it enters in the event i created with on(..) but the event target is not the ListItem, but the ListItemLabel. However, the label is slightly smaller than the item, and when I click in that small accesible space of the ListItem, the event.target is the ListItem. The problem is obvious, I would have to check the type of item that is entering the method to get the info that I need one way or another...

1. Is there any way to force that, if I click anywhere in the ListItem, this is the element that will be the target of the event??
2. Why ListItemLabel is entering on that method if I connected the handler to the ListItiem?
3. Is there any way to connect the handler exclusively to the ListItem and NOT the child nodes??

Thank you a lot in advance!!

Comment: you want when you click on li you get always it's ID ?

Comment: Yes. It would be something like.... i want the child items of the li to fire the click event of their parent (which is the li). I have been googling around, but there are not many examples with dojo..

Comment: see my below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities , the first one is to compare if the event.target equals your li element, if so then get directly the id otherwise get target parent and acces the li id .

The second is just to use the currently click element context (`this`) , knowing that you have to remove the `lang.hitch` function to prevent executing the event in the globale context ( `window` context in this case ) So remove the `lang.hitch` because you're not using it inside the click (no need of calling context here), and the `this` will refer to your clicked `li` element and the id is just acceses by `this.id` .

See below worknig snippet :

```js
require(["dojo/ready","dojo/dom","dojo/dom-construct","dojo/on","dojo/_base/lang","dojox/mobile/parser", "dojox/mobile/Icon", "dojox/mobile/RoundRectList", "dojox/mobile/ListItem"], function (ready, dom, domConstruct, on, lang, parser, Icon, RoundRectList, ListItem) {
  var paneaux = dom.byId("personsListPane");
  var list = new RoundRectList({
      id: 'personsList',
      select:"single",
  }).placeAt(paneaux).startup();
 
  var listaux = dom.byId("personsList");
  for (var i = 1, len = 5; i < len; i++) {
    //var person= persons[i];
    var li = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
        id:i,
        label: "Surname" + i,
        clickable : true,
    }, domConstruct.create("li", {}, listaux));

    li.startup();
  
    on(li, "click", function(evt){
      console.log("Id of clicked = "+ this.id);
      /*var person = gpt._sessionData.userPersons.filter(function(obj){
        return obj.IdPerson==li.id;
      });                         
      gpt._sessionData.defaultPersonEmployee =person[0];
      initImpl();*/
    }); 
  }
  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 65px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojox//mobile/themes/iphone/iphone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<div id="personsListPane"></div>
```